# Linked List: Inserting a name and id number to list

Tags: c, insert, linked-list

Need help inserting a name and id number into a list. Crashes whenever try 
add in number into list

```
struct node {

int id;
char name[50];
struct node *next;
} *head;


struct node *insert(struct node * list, char nam[50], int id){

struct node *helper;
struct node *pNew;
pNew=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

strcpy(pNew->name, nam);
pNew->id = id;
pNew->next=NULL;

helper=list;

if (list == NULL)
    return pNew;

while (helper->next!=NULL)
    helper=helper->next;

helper->next=pNew;


return list;
```

}

```
int main()
{

char nameInsert[50];
char nameDelete[50];
int idNum, i;
struct node *n=NULL;

//beginning of linked list, must initialize
head = NULL;

//read in data using file input function
readDataFile();

//display data operations using while loop
while(1)
{
    printf("\nData Operations\n");
    printf("\n--------------\n");
    printf("1. Insert Name\n");
    printf("2. Display Names\n");
    printf("3. Delete by ID Number\n");
    printf("4. Delete by Name\n");
    printf("5. Exit\n");
    printf("Please enter a command: ");

    if(scanf("%d", &i) <= 0)
    {
        printf("Not valid input, please use integers 1 - 5");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        //beginning of switch case
        switch(i)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("Enter the name you would like to insert: ");
                scanf("%s",nameInsert);
                printf("Enter the ID number associated with the name: ");
                scanf("%d", &idNum);
                insert(n,nameInsert, idNum); //insert function
                break;
```

Application that reads in a data file and stores the data as a linked list.
Prompt the user for the student’s namePrompt the user for the student’s id numberPopulate an instance of the linked list node with the dataAdd the new node to the existing linked list

Comment: Please do not cast the return value of `malloc()` and family.

Comment: Please show us `pNew->name` is allocated memory or not. is `name` a `char *`?

Comment: Please show us the definition of `struct node`

Comment: `if(scanf("%d", &i) <= 0)` i think you got the logic a bit wrong. `scanf()` returns the number of items successfully scanned, not the input value.

Comment: It takes me to the correct case. It asks me for the name then the id then it crashes. It gives me this error': (lldb)

Comment: It takes me to the correct case. It asks me for the name then the id then it crashes. It gives me this error: (lldb)

Comment: `helper` is local to `insert()`. and can you please use `gdb` to find out the exact line where it is crashing?

Comment: I am using Xcode on mac.

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified and amended your `insert()` function

```
struct node *insert(struct node * list, char *nam, int id){
    struct node *pNew;
    pNew=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (pNew == NULL) {
        printf ("Unable to allocate memory\n")
        exit (1);
    }
    strncpy(pNew->name, nam, 49);       // limit the string copy length
    pNew->name[49] = 0;                 // precautionary terminator
    pNew->id = id;
    pNew->next = list;                  // point to list passed
    return pNew;                        // return new list
}
```

And the way you call `insert()` ignores its return value, which is the new list head/root.

```
n = insert(n, nameInsert, idNum);   // use the return value
```